# unable to run in glassfish, bizarre input stream errors in log

Tags: java, jsp, maven, glassfish

Trying to deploy my application to glassfish and while the application appears to deploy successfully the newly added servlet and its jsp appear blank. Checking the logs I see dozens of entries that look like this

```
[2014-09-30T10:34:40.311-0400] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00048] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1412087680311] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Invalid InputStream returned for org/hibernate/hql/internal/ast/tree/UpdateStatement.class]]
```

Presumably one for each class in my library. Checking glassfish_home/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications I was able to find the first few I checked. I opted not to look for them all, there appear to be hundreds.

All I can find online is that NCLS-CORE-00048 means severe, which isn't helpful. Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is your database server started? and accessible?

Comment: Yes. I'm running Derby and it's up and running. Other parts of the application are able to pull data from it. Just my one page is failing.

Edit: I should also note that while I picked a hibernate class as an example, there are dozens of classes throwing that same error from several different libraries. There's one from Terracotta, for example, which I didn't even realize we were using.

Answer (score 1):

I found an issue that seems similar to yours [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/568354/open-source/Glassfish-deployment-issues).

As seen in the last post, check your WEB-INF and remove the jboss-system jar if it exists. It seems that jar conflicts with Glassfish.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately no such jar exists. :-(